# Python typing with recursive types and protocols

Tags: python, python-typing

I am trying to find a nicer way of statically typing the following code without the repetition:

```
import numpy as np
from typing import Any, Iterable, Mapping, Sequence, Tuple, Union, Protocol

Shape = Sequence[Union[int, np.int32, np.int64]]
ShapeTree = Union[Shape, Iterable['ShapeTree'], Mapping[Any, 'ShapeTree']]

class InitFn_1(Protocol):
    def __call__(self, input_shape: Shape) -> Shape:
        ...

class InitFn_2(Protocol):
    def __call__(self, input_shape: Shape) -> ShapeTree:
        ...

class InitFn_3(Protocol):
    def __call__(self, input_shape: ShapeTree) -> Shape:
        ...

class InitFn_4(Protocol):
    def __call__(self, input_shape: ShapeTree) -> ShapeTree:
        ...

InitFn = Union[InitFn_1, InitFn_2, InitFn_3, InitFn_4]
```

Is there a shorter way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

Note that the sum of all cases os equivalent to `Callable[[Shape | ShapeTree], Shape | ShapeTree]`

```py
from typing import Any, Iterable, Mapping, Sequence, Union, Protocol

import numpy as np

Shape = Sequence[Union[int, np.int32, np.int64]]
ShapeTree = Union[Shape, Iterable["ShapeTree"], Mapping[Any, "ShapeTree"]]


class InitFn(Protocol):
    def __call__(self, input_shape: Shape | ShapeTree) -> Shape | ShapeTree:
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  The issue with this solution is that for example:
`def f(input_shape: Shape) -> Shape: return input_shape`
will not be recognized a instance of the Protocol because, with this method, the instances of the Protocol must be able to receive both `Shape` and `ShapeTree`

Comment: Alright, so if you want to declare `InitFn` as a `Union` of the mentioned cases, then I think there is no shortcut for this - you have to declare each type in order to declare the union of those types.